# Digital Pen to fill in a custom form

Tags: digital-pen

I'm looking for a digital pen to fill in custom forms on paper. I want to create a form on my PC, print it, fill it out and upload the result/form to my PC.

There are some companies that provide this service:

- Digital Field Solutions - Uses a Formworks server
- Gaseway Solutions - Solutions for business sector
- Digital Pen Corp - Uses a Digital Pen Corp server
- Netpage Digital Pen - Just a YouTube video? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvbszOD68lQ). I couldn't find the product online.

What I want is to create and read custom forms without a 3rd party in between.

- Does this kind of Digital Pen exist?
- Does a software exist that I can use with a standard Digital Pen?

**UPDATE:**

I have a form where I can enter some standard information about a client (e.g. name / address / etc.). When I visit a client I fill in the form and when I am back at the office I  transcript the information to a digital copy of the form. I now want to remove the transcription part. (I already tried to use a laptop, but it's faster to enter the date by hand. And I also use sometimes sketches.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered skipping the printing step and doing the whole thing digitally? You can make your forms fillable (at least with Acrobat Pro, I'm not sure what you're using and if that's what you mean by "3rd party in between"). If you require a signature at the end you can print, sign like normal, and scan back into your computer. OR you could get a tablet (like what Wacom makes) and sign on your computer as well which would keep things entirely on your computer if digitization is your goal.

Comment: Thank you for your response - I have edited my question - I hope my problem is now more clear.